# php cURL mutiple response error 500

Tags: php, curl

When I run code second, response 500 err:

> 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How to fix?
My code:

```
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    $ch2 = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    $headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html';

    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nhuyexpress.com.vn/view-order/?matracuu=1ZY10Y950301862805");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nhuyexpress.com.vn/view-order/?matracuu=1ZY10Y950301862805");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //create the multiple cURL handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    //add the two handles
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);

    //close the handles
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
    curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Response I recieve

[image]

Comment: Check server logfiles.

Comment: *"500 **Internal** Server Error"* Check your server error_log file.